# facebook registration form integration

Tags: html, facebook, integration, registration

I have mad a website and I wanted to include a Facebook registration form using Facebook Developers. I created an account and made an app. When I copy and paste the html for the registration form I put in my app id where it says (in the code) and I put in a redirect url (landing page that says: you have created an account or something). When I enter in the code it comes up with this text: Unable to load the registration form for Developer Site. You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: 'redirect_uri' should be an absolute url.)  I went into my privacy settings and nothing was blocked. Can anyone help to understand why this says this? My website is http://waybored.com if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code actually looks like:

```
<div id="283932682341116322" align="left" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;" class="wcustomhtml"><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=113869198637480&
             redirect_uri=
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
</iframe></div>
```

You have line breaks and lots of whitespace in the `src` value you are giving for the iframe.

And that you have not given any value for the `redirect_uri` parameter is what it says in the error message too.